# tensorflow.keras.losses.cosine_similarity returns positive values in TensorFlow 1.15

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Not sure if I am doing something wrong here, but for whatever reason when I follow the example for tf 2.4.1 [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/cosine_similarity)

I don't get the same results, in fact, I get the negative of the result in the example.

Here's what I am doing

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.losses import cosine_similarity

y_true = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.], [1., 1.]]
y_pred = [[1., 0.], [1., 1.], [-1., -1.]]

loss = cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred, axis=1) 
loss_numpy = loss.eval(session=tf.Session())

print(loss_numpy) # array([ 0.        ,  0.99999994, -0.99999994], dtype=float32)
# expected output array([-0.        , -0.99999994,  0.99999994], dtype=float32)
```

I am assuming this is not the case in tf 2+, but is this a known issue that I just have to deal with, or is something else going on?

P.S.

I have gone around that by defining

```
cosine_proximity_loss = lambda y_true, y_pred: -1. * cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred)
```

and using that in my model. If anyone knows that I should not do this any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your fault, for some historical reasons, `tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity` in `tf v1.15` will only return cosine value, but in `tf v2.4.1` will return negative cosine value.

[tf v1.15 source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.0/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1071-L1075) of `tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity`:

```
y_true = nn.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=axis)
y_pred = nn.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=axis)
return math_ops.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=axis)
```

[tf v2.4.1 source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1729-L1731) of `tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity`:

```
y_true = nn.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=axis)
y_pred = nn.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=axis)
return -math_ops.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=axis)
```

So, if you want using `tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity` in `tf v1.15` as same way as in `tf v2.4.1`, just add minus sign before it outputs

Comment: Huh, that's funny. I suppose 2.x uses the negative similarity because it's used as a loss function, so reducing it should make it "better". They could have reframed it as "cosine distance"...

Comment: @xdurch0 Funny indeed : )